# null pointer exception. why?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am a java newbie, so forgive me if this question may sound stupid. I am learning.

I am trying to calculate this sum but I am getting a strange error message. Can you help me find me where it is? Thank you so much

```
public class myfirstjavaclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer myfirstinteger = new Integer(1);
        Integer mysecondinteger = new Integer(2);
        Integer mythirdinteger = null;
        Integer result = myfirstinteger/mythirdinteger;
    }

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at myfirstjavaclass.main(myfirstjavaclass.java:8)
```

Comment: `mythirdinteger = null;` then `myfirstinteger/mythirdinteger` which would equate to `1 / null`?

Comment: Just a hint:  `(myfirstjavaclass.java:8)` means that it happened on line 8.  Is there any null pointer ("reference") on that line??

Comment: "why it's not zero?" - Because this isn't C.

Comment: The object types are being converted into literal types because of the operator. However, a null cannot be converted into a literal, so you get this exception.

Comment: @Mary: I'd just like to say - you may find your first experience with SO quite disconcerting.  We are regrettably a user base that is geared toward users with some programming experience.  Please don't let that discourage you on your journey to learning programming.  Good luck!

Comment: zero = new Integer(0). null is just another thing, lady

Comment: Because `null` is nothing, it has no meaning and thus Java doesn't know how it should be treated...

Comment: "a user base that is geared toward users with some programming experience." of which a good chunk seems to have forgotten that they were newbies too once.

Comment: Related (a little) http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/158908/why-null-pointer-instead-of-class-cast

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you divided by `null`, of course. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Why does attempting to divide by null throw a NullPointerException? Why not a DivideByNullException or some other more explanatory exception.

Comment: The answer isn't entirely this trivial, as pointed out by @ChrisDennett in the comments... the OP is a newbie, you don't have to be rude.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko something to do with auto boxing, feel free to supply a more detailed answer.

Comment: @mellamokb I could have just posted this as a comment, but it was also an answer, so I posted it as an answer. I'm not sure why dividing by `null` and getting an exception is surprising. It's standard practice to post a quick incomplete answer on an SO question. If your question is so incomplete that comments and answers are interchangeable I wouldn't really take that out on the answerer.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `Integer` (the object type) here, as it can be `null` (which you don't need and trip over here).

When you dereference a `null` in Java, you get a NullPointerException.

In this case, it is a bit tricky, because automatic unboxing is involved (fancy name for conversion between the primitive types and their object wrappers).
What happens under the hood is that

```
Integer result = myfirstinteger/mythirdinteger;
```

is really compiled as

```
Integer result = Integer.valueOf(
     myfirstinteger.intValue() / mythirdinteger.intValue());
```

The call to `intValue()` fails on a null pointer.

Just use `int` (the primitive).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myfirstinteger = 1;
    int mysecondinteger = 2;
    int mythirdinteger = 0;
    int result = myfirstinteger/mythirdinteger; 
       // will still fail, you cannot divide by 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it seems to me your third Integer is assigned to null.

BTW, what do you really want to do? 
If you want to calculate a sum like you said in your question, see the code below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int first = 1;
    int second = 2;
    int third = 0;
    int sum = first + second + third;
}
```

If you want to calculate product, make sure you are not dividing by 0

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int first = 1;
    int second = 2;
    int product = first / second; // this product is 0, because you are forcing an int
    double product2 = (double) first / second; // this will be 0.5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Null" means "this variable doesn't reference anything", which is another way of saying "this variable has no value".  It doesn't mean "the value is zero".

A NullPointerException is what Java gives you when you use a variable that doesn't reference anything, in a context that requires the variable to have a value.  Dividing a number by the value of a variable is a context which requires the variable to have a value - hence the exception.